# Pentaho and AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: pentaho, aws-secrets-manager

Iwould like to keep passwords to databases in AWS Secrets Manager and be able to use them by jobs running from Pentaho (PDI) which is installed on AWS EC2 instance.

What will be the best way to build such solution? I don't really want to keep the passwords on the EC2 instance.

Regards,
Rafal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, authentication with AWS Secrets Manager requires the submission of AWS Signature Version 4, the method of calculating it is described here: [Calculate the signature for AWS Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html)

Unfortunately, the REST Client component does not support AWS authentication and signature calculation, so that separate components would be needed to calculate it or you can do it using ready-made libraries, e.g. Python boto3.

To connect to AWS Secrets Manager, you can use a ready-made Boto3 library in Python and use it in the Python Executor component in PDI

[image: PDI - Python Executor example]

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question, it is possible to use REST API:
•   AWS > Documentation > AWS Secrets Manager > API Reference
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
GetSecretValue

and using REST Client step in PDI:
https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.3/Products/REST_Client